# The InstallExecuteSequence table contains an action 'RemoveExistingProducts' that is declared in two different locations

Tags: .net, wix, upgrade

Following recommendations from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/19/9006538.aspx to retain config files during WiX upgrade, I've added the following line to InstallExecuteSequence:

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFiles"></RemoveExistingProducts>
```

When compiling WiX solution the following error pops up:

```
The InstallExecuteSequence table contains an action 'RemoveExistingProducts' that is declared in two different locations.  Please remove one of the actions or set the Overridable='yes' attribute on one of their elements.
```

Why does this occur? And how to fix it?

Comment: You must have declared **RemoveExistingProducts** twice in your source file. Search for it, and remove it.

Comment: @Glytzhkof Search returns one occurrence of **RemoveExistingProducts**, which is the line I've added.

Comment: MajorUpgrade also schedules RemoveExistingProducts perhaps that is where the conflict is coming from

Answer (score 4):

You should try to remove this line:

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFiles"></RemoveExistingProducts>
```

and add **Schedule="afterInstallExecute"** to the [**MajorUpgrade Element**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) like this:

```
<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallExecute" 
              DowngradeErrorMessage="Newer version installed. Exiting." />
```

Comment: Thanks, @Glytzhkof! This helped to get rid of the error.